# How to use the result of a query in another select statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I have a table A, and it contains 10 rows and 3 columns. One of the columns is `name` and these are table names.

I have written a query

```
select name from A
```

Now iIwant to use the value of all 10 names (as table names) in other query. How can I do this in Sybase?

Comment: Actually original table (A)contains the name of database tables satisfying any particular criteria(say they are user table or admin tables) . And i want to use the name of these table one by one (say in any update or delete query)

Comment: yeah ..basically i need to know the name of each tables satisfying some criteria and then need to use those names one by one in other query . My doubt is how will i collect name of tables in any variable?Any variable in sybase just stores the last value of the result of select.

Comment: @Aditya Don't think 'one by one' in SQL. Think about sets. You now have a set a names - you can do set based on operations on them which includes joins, selects, where, exists etc.

Comment: Why do you need to use them one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a result set for a `JOIN`

```
SELECT [B].*
FROM [B]
    INNER JOIN (SELECT [Name] FROM [A]) aliasA
    ON [B].[Name] = aliasA.[Name]
```

or you can use a result set for a `WHERE`

```
SELECT [B].*
FROM [B]
WHERE [B].[Name] IN 
    (SELECT [Name] FROM [A])
```

You can also use it in a variety of other ways. In most scenarios you can treat a result set as though it were a table - select from it, join with it, etc.

Comment: I get the impression that the OP wants to use the names as table names rather than simply joining to a derived table. More of a `foreach name in result_set; do select * from name; done` sort of thing.

Comment: ya @muistooshort ..i want to do exactly same thing that you are refering to..is the method "foreach name in result_set; do select * from name; done " works in sybase? and also will result_set mentioned in above for loop be a query?

Comment: @kirk Broadhurst : can you help with above?

Comment: If you explain what you want to do, then I'll see if I know how to help. As I said above, you should generally steer away from `foreach` type logic in SQL.

Comment: i want to take backup of all the tables beginning with some particular name ..there are 10 tables..so first i am finding the table names from DB using name%, then i want to collect the data from each table and store in filesystem(using bcp), then i want to delete the data from the above tables.(This i want to do on regular basis)

Comment: i am thinking of writing a shell script for that..so instead of writing 10 delete queries and 10 bcp statements(for each table name)..i want to write single bcp and single delete statement. This will help in scaling the code also .